# Cordova plugins stop working, need to remove and re-add them (too) often

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

I'm working on a cordova project that needs to be deployed on both Android and iOS and I'm having some issues with plugins I installed via cordova cli (command line interface).

This ONLY seems to happen on the iOS side of things but that could be because I mostly work on a Windows machine and push changes to a mac and build the iOS app there (see below)

The only way to fix it is to remove the plugin (cordova plugin remove [plugin] --save) and then add it again (cordova plugin add [plugin] --save). It's happened with both StatusBar and SocialSharing plugins.

Some background:

- I work on multiple machines. Two of those are windows on which I do most of the work and build the Android app. The other is a mac. I use that one as little as possible (I don't like OSX and mac keyboard shortcuts) but I need it to build the iOS app.
- I sync between the machines via subversion (svn). I ignore the platforms/ and plugins/ folders so it's basically only the www/ folder and the config.xml that change. After a 'svn up' I run cordova prepare.
- I use Cordova 6.3.1, iOS platform 4.2.1, OSX El Capitan

Oh, whenever I call the plugin in javascript code it doesn't throw any errors. It just doesn't work, nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug, maybe?

**UPDATE**

Config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>AppName</name>
    <description>
        Blabla
    </description>
    <author email="email@host.com" href="http://website.com/">
        Me!
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.1.3" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#5ca829" />
    <feature name="SocialSharing">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SocialSharing" />
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
    </feature>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="~5.1.2" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.2" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.1" />
</widget>
```

(The config is a bit of a mess but that's because cordova keeps shuffling things around, I've given up on keeping it tidy at least for now)

Plugins that are affected (yep, it's multiple):

- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

It seems to happen every time I add a plugin on machine X and then check it out on machine Y (the latter being the mac) which causes cordova prepare to install the plugins that are declared in the config but are not found on the system. I've also tested by removing the platforms/ and(/or) plugins/ folder and then run 'cordova prepare', I get the same problem.

It seems the prepare commando does add them but not properly? Maybe?

Comment: Can you show us the config.xml file ? (with plugins saved)

Comment: I guess this is a third party plugin. If yes, kindly share which plugin you are using to understand better

Comment: Updated the question with config.xml and some minor details

Comment: @REJH i did the same thing for my development and dint faced any prob in iOS. Only difference is i copy the project folder manually to mac machine and remove and readd platform before building IPA

Comment: @Gandhi besides the platform folder, do you also remove the plugins folder or do you leave that and just (re)add the platforms?

Comment: @REJH I dont manipulate the plugin folder. I just copy the plugin folder as is from windows to mac. Also i never use --save option too while adding plugin. Hence, when you add platform in iOS, it refers fetch.json file in plugin folder to install the plugins to the platform. Works for me fine.